# デフォルトのキーをマクロで変更するマクロは可能でしょうか？

Tags: emeditor

お世話になっております。
再変換の確定キーをスペース以外に毎時変更するマクロは可能でしょうか？
たぶんデフォルトでは自動的にスペースになっていると思いますが、任意に割当を適示変更できるマクロになります。
これはEmEditorじたいでのカスタマイズではなく、マクロで設定で実行時毎時に設定できますでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

説明の追加です。

例文
ほっかいどうのらーめんがいがにぎわっています。
げんちでたっぷりとたのしみたいけど、りょこうにいけないじきはおとりよせするというのもてです。
きょうはくしろほうめんにいきます。
ねむろではのっさっぷみさききにいきます。

このような例文があったとします。

https://www.atok.com/dic/add.html

これを通常のEmEditorの再変換コマンドでやると、上記のサイトで言うと普段、自分が使っているメインの1番の辞書で変換されますので、

「言質でたっぷりと楽しみたいけど、旅行に行けない次期はお取り寄せするというのも手ですよ！」

EmEditorで再変換するとこのようになります。インストール直後の初期の辞書でやると普通に正確に変換できます。
本来はちゃんと"現地"とか"時期"と変換できるのにおかしな変換になる原因は、1番の辞書は普段から使っている学習効果や単語登録の辞書の優先順位に影響するためです。
普段から言質とかそういう変換を多用していると1番の辞書はもっともよく使う単語が優先変換されるように自動的に学習しているので通常文に使うとユーザー特有の使用癖が優先されて純粋な変換にならないです。

そこで回避策は再変換のときは、IMEの辞書の割当機能でまっさらの何も学習していないIME本来の変換を引き出すには、2番以降の初期状態の辞書(ユーザーの使用履歴のない辞書)でF5とかを変換キーに割り当てないと、普段自分が使用の単語が出てきてメチャクチャな変換になります。

これは、
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4199);  // 再変換
shell.SendKeys( "~" );

この shell.SendKeys( "~" );エンタキーの部分をF5とかに変えても1番の辞書を使うという動作は変化しませんでした。
これはおそらく再変換のコマンドのコード自身にスペースキーを押すという動作もプログラムに同時に含まれているためと思います。
再変換をスペースキーではなく、F5とかに変更できますでしょうか？という質問になります。

IME側で普段の辞書をF5にしてスペースキーを初期の辞書にすると、再変換がおかしくなる問題は解決しますが、普段の変換がたいへん使いにくくなります。そのため一時使用のマクロのときだけスペースキーの割当をF5とかにできれば全部解決します。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 文字入力周りの操作は IME や OS が担っているものと思われますが、これをテキストエディタのマクロで制御しようとするのは妥当でしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。使い分けは単純に変換時に操作するボタンの組み合わせを変えるだけで辞書などの使い分けが出来ますので高度な要求をしているわけではありません。非常に単純なことです。デフォルトはスペースキーが割り当てられていますが、それを別のキーにもマクロで変えられますかという質問です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

再変換の確定キーは、IME側で設定するものですので、EmEditorのマクロでの設定は難しいと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。辞書の使い分け方法で変換時に押すキーの組み合わせでユーザー辞書が変えられるようです。たとえばF5キーにするとかです。
https://www.atok.com/dic/add.html　マクロで無理でしたら、設定の所では可能でしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: そしたら、F5 など別のキーを使えばいいのだけのことだと思うのですが、シンプルなサンプルなどを示して、ご質問の意味を明確化していただけると幸いです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問を追記致しました。

Comment: そうすると、`SendKeys` メソッドで `F5` を送るにはどう書けばいいか、というご質問でしょうか?

Comment: ありがとうございます。そうなんですが、以下の記述ではうまくいきませんでした。   辞書の使い分けはどう書けば行けますでしょうか？ editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4199); 
    shell.SendKeys( "{F5}" );

Comment: `shell.SendKeys( "{F5}" );` だとどのように動作しないのでしょうか?「辞書の使い分け」の意味を教えていただけますか? ご質問の要点を簡潔にお願いいたします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。辞書の使い分けの意味は普段の単語登録の影響を一切受けないようにするためです。shell.SendKeys( "{F5}" );でも辞書の切替にはなっていませんでした。動作しないというのは通常のスペースキーで変換するときの動作になります。editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4199); このコマンド自体にスペースキーを押す動作が含まれているのではないでしょうか？手動で通常のように変換するときにスペースキーの代わりにF5とかを押すと動作していますので、EmEditorでもバージョンアップしていただければ辞書の使い分けができるようになるはずです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4199)` は、[再変換] コマンドで、スペースを押す動作は含まれていません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。 editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4199);とshell.SendKeys( "{F2}");  これを同時に押すという記述は可能でしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。調べてみたら再変換コマンドを使わずにshift+変換キーの組み合わせでも可能なことがわかりました。http://www.emeditor.org/ja/macro_shell_send_keys.html　ここには変換キーの書き方が書いていないのですがどう書きますでしょうか？editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4199)　このコマンド無しでも再変換が可能なようです。

Comment: 手動で以下の方法ではできる可能性がたかいことがわかりました。1行選択→shift+変換キー→F2キー→エンターキー、これをマクロ再現できれば可能っぽい感じでした。shift+変換キーで一度はメイン辞書が出てきますが、次にF2が押されたことで辞書が切り替わるようです。

Comment: お世話になっております。　http://www.emeditor.org/ja/macro_shell_send_keys.html こちらのページでは書いてないキーが多いようです。Windowsキーもありませんでした。全部のキーのマニュアル記載をお願いできますでしょうか？

Comment: ご質問内容が、`SendKeys` メソッドについてと、変わってきていますので、別スレッドで、ご質問の要点だけを簡潔に書いていただけると幸いです。